# Atom open file in new pane

Tags: atom-editor

I want to open a file in Atom but I don't just want it to open in a new tab but in a new pane, so that I have a split screen.
Is that possible somehow?

Best Regards
Raphael

Answer (score 0):

right mouse click and click one of the options:

[image]

another way you can use one of the following commands from commands-pallete (default shortcut is `ctrl-shift-p`).

```
window:move-active-item-to-pane-above
window:move-active-item-to-pane-below
window:move-active-item-to-pane-on-right
window:move-active-item-to-pane-on-left

pane:split-up-and-move-active-item
pane:split-down-and-move-active-item
pane:split-left-and-move-active-item
pane:split-right-and-move-active-item

window:copy-active-item-to-pane-above
window:copy-active-item-to-pane-below
window:copy-active-item-to-pane-on-right
window:copy-active-item-to-pane-on-left

pane:split-up-and-copy-active-item
pane:split-down-and-copy-active-item
pane:split-left-and-copy-active-item
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that this works but I want it to do that automatically. The reason for that is that I want to be able to compile a latex-file and open the PDF automatically on the right half of the window. I am using script to compile the file and I am using atom as the default pdf-previewer. After compiling, the file opens but in the same pane. Is there maybe a package or something that would solve my problem?

Comment: if you use atom package 'latex' there is option "Pdf View Split Direction" which is you are looking for